# Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function (FireBase documentation)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from my Firestore database. Based on [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_2) I wrote this:

```
const productsRef = db.collection('products');
const snapshot = await productsRef.get();
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

I get the error in the title. Why do they share a code that doesn't work or am I missed something? Thank you!

Comment: You are using `await` outside of the context of an async function.  That's not valid JavaScript.  We can't see the function in which you've placed this code, so there's nothing more to say.

Comment: The keyword `await` does not appear on the page you linked. *edit* oh yes it does. They just did a bad job with the Node examples. If you click through to the source page, you'll see that those code fragments are indeed inside `async` functions.

Comment: This is how it should be used: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/537d1a6fb2aebc5c91cda65dde1233a674f0ca50/firestore/main/index.js#L511-L524 (inside an `async` function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `async` function in order to use the `await` keyword.
If you don't have a function in wich this code is ran you can use an IIFE wrapper

```
(async ()=>{
  const productsRef = db.collection('products');
  const snapshot = await productsRef.get();
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
})();
```

or don't use await at all and handle it into the `then` chain :

```
const productsRef = db.collection('products');
const snapshot = productsRef.get().then((snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible, that this function broke jQuery functions? The code below this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: It's unlikely for this particular code to break the $, however, if for example `db` is null or undefined in its context, it can crash the whole script. Check your console (F12) and see if there are any errors logged.

Answer (score 1):

The `await` keyword is used for consuming promises, along with `async`. But in order for await to work you must wrap it inside a function declared with the `async` keyword, like so:

```
const getProducts = async () => {
  const productsRef = db.collection('products');
  const snapshot = await productsRef.get();
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  });
}

getProducts();
```